# Is there a IMarkupExtension<T> for WPF?

Tags: wpf

Is there a `IMarkupExtension<T>` for WPF? 
if not, will WPF 4.5 have it?

Comment: For the record though, as a guy who uses SL pretty frequently, I pretty much always extend MarkupExtension anyway (which is IMarkupExtension<object>).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No and no. WPF isn't generic friendly.